# Tagged string automatically disabled after posting the question

Tags: support, tags

When I posted the question linked below, ( now its updated using Ctrl +k)

[Oracle extract values from xmltype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544610/oracle-extract-values-from-xmltype)

In my question the paragraph....one data in the i_xml from now onwards and I will only have either name or age tags .", 
I used `<>` tag for name and age.

But after i posted the question, the name and age word completely disappeared.

So Can I know the reason behind it?

Thanks in advance.

I'm new to meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that the `<>` were gone from your question here as well.

Why? Because `<>` need to be escaped when in HTML. You need to add a ` before and after any `<>` so we know to escape an show them.

So, in a large code block, simply ensure everything is indented 4 spaces. The keyboard shortcut for these is <kbd>Ctrl + k</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks.. I noticed the same 'illusion' after your answer.